# PrimeFaces Extensions not showing

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

i have the following jar files in my lib folder in my dynamic-web-project:

[image]

Now i want to show a simple clock from PrimeFaces extensions:

```
  <h:panelGrid>
            <p:panel>
                <pe:analogClock/>
            </p:panel>
  </h:panelGrid>
```

But i can't see anything. Just the panel is showing and the right height and width from that clock, but no clock itself, just an empty panel.

[image]

So, why is that happend?

Comment: Did you check the html? Browser console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement jsf dude with its respective jars.
You'll need the javax.faces-"version".jar, the jsf-impl-"version".jar (both, javax and jsf-impl, have to be the same version), and jstl.jar and I think It will run.